# adding additional criteria to script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script that logs entries made into column 4 on the sheet named 'Postcode Checker' and places them in the sheet called 'app_search_logs'.

I want to add further criteria whereby the script will also log entries made in columns 10,11,12,13 and 14 of the sheet 'Postcode Checker' and place these in a sheet called 'PUB_search_logs'. I have tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work properly with the changes I made.

How can I get this to do what I want?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.'
    );
  }
  logColumns_(e);
}
 
/**
* Automatically logs changes in columnsToWatch in sheetsToWatch.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function logColumns_(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 10 February 2022
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/150138311
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 30 July 2014
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/7CaJ_nYfLnM/discussion
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 10 August 2013
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/az365_ypIV0
  if (!e.value) {
    return;
  }
 
  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  const parameters = [
    {
      sheetsToWatch: /^(Postcode Checker)$/i,
      columnsToWatch: [4],
      changelogSheetName: 'app_search_logs',
    
    },
  ];
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////
 
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  const settings = parameters.filter(setting => sheetName.match(setting.sheetsToWatch))[0];
  if (!settings || !settings.columnsToWatch.includes(e.range.columnStart) || sheetName === settings.changelogSheetName) {
    return;
  }
  const columnLabel = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  const rowLabel = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, sheet.getFrozenColumns() || 1).getValue();
  let changelogSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(settings.changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    changelogSheet = e.source
      .insertSheet(settings.changelogSheetName, e.source.getNumSheets())
      .appendRow(['Timestamp', 'Sheet name', 'Cell address', 'Column label', 'Row label', 'Value entered']);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an idea you can try with the following. From the script above, instead of the last line

```
changelogSheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value]);
```

I added:

```
const pubSearchLogShet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PUB_search_logs");
  const col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col == 4){
    changelogSheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])    
  }

  else if(col == 10 ||col == 11 ||col == 12 ||col == 13 ||col == 14){
    pubSearchLogShet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])
  }
}
```

I also modified `columnsToWatch` in `paramaters`:

```
  const parameters = [
    {
      sheetsToWatch: /^(Postcode Checker)$/i,
      columnsToWatch: [4,10,11,12,13,14],
      changelogSheetName: 'app_search_logs'    
    },
  ];
```